# Add dynamic URL to Leaflet iconUrl

Tags: leaflet, javascript, jquery, cordova

I need to custom icon for my app . One icon for a group of markers. I add a URL for each icone and I don't know how to add it dynamically to my iconUrl. It to change for each select.

Here is my code :  I tried this but I don't even know if it works!

```
function displayIconByCAt(iconUrl) {
    console.log(iconUrl);

 var data = iconUrl.toString(data);
    console.log(data);
    createNewIcon(data);
}
function createNewIcon(data){
    var iconMarkers = L.icon({
        iconUrl:'',
        iconSize: [38, 38], // size of the icon

        iconAnchor: [22, 94], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location

        popupAnchor: [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAncho
    })
    var iconNew = iconUrl;
    var value = data;

    console.log(iconNew);
    console.log(value);

    iconMarkers [iconNew] = value;

    console.log(iconMarkers[iconNew]);

}
console.log(iconMarkers);
```

Comment: thanks for  correction but do you have an idea about my code ?

Comment: From your decription it's hard to gues what you want to achieve. Is this correct: you want to dynamically create icons with different images, depending on some data parameter and store them in some array for later use?

Comment: i have an initial map and i want to add markers on it depending to the choise of a category. Each categories  has one icon and differents markers with this icon.

Comment: Of what nature is this category? Number, string, something else? What is this `iconUrl` you are using in your code?

Comment: I find a sololution, it was simple but i'm not sure its really ok :